# sphinx search any variations from the initial search words

Tags: sphinx

How possible in sphinxsearch for example `Lorem ipsum dolor`

find first

```
Lorem ipsum dolor
```

then

```
Lorem ipsum   
ipsum dolor
Lorem dolor
```

then

```
Lorem  
ipsum
ipsum
```

Any variations from the initial search words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use extended query and write it as

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor"/1
```

which basically says only one of the words is **required** (quorum syntax).

Then play with using different ranking modes. 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#builtin-rankers

`WORDCOUNT` would be pretty good for this, but maybe a bit primitive.

Try `MATCHANY` ranker - its the ranker from the old match any mode, but is still pretty good for these types of queries.